# How to get the last element of array from key array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

```
  $parent = array(
            array(//$parent[0]
               "a-key",
               "b-key" => array(
                            array("1", "2", "3"), //b-key[0]

                            array("4", "5", "6")) //b-key[1]                              
                ,
               "c-key"),

            array(//$parent[1]
               "a-key",
               "b-key" => array(array("7", "8", "9"), //b-key[0]
                                array("10", "16",      //b-key[1]  
                                            "12" => array(array("13"),   //12[0]
                                                          array("14"))), //12[1]

                                array("15", "16" => array(), "17"))      //b-key[2] 
               ,                                            
               "c-key"),

               array(//$parent[2]
               "a-key",
               "b-key" => array(array("7", "8", "9"), //b-key[0]
                                array("10", "16",      //b-key[1]  
                                            "12" => array(array("13"),   //12[0]
                                                          array("14"))), //12[1]

                                array("15", "16" => array(), "17"))      //b-key[2] 
               ,                                            
               "c-key")
        );
```

Requirement:

step1: Go to `$parent` last element (i.e.) `$parent[2]`

step2: From `$parent[1]` check all the key which has array value. Here `b-key` has array value. Go to `b-key` last element (i.e.) `b-key[3]`

step3: From `b-key[3]` check all the key which has array value. Here `16` has array value. Append new data here.

Expected output:`"16"=>array(array("newdata"))`

Comment: `end()` moves the pointer..  the next step is to get the key via `key()`  you may consider first walking/traversing the array structure and returning a pointer/reference..  then work with the reference.

Comment: Then, in this case which method I can use?

Comment: I don't get it, why would you want to push data to an unknown key (or series of unknown keys...)? That will make it a lot harder to get it back / to use it.

Comment: key name is known. I want to insert data to the known keys. Am using loop to insert data . Every time it should insert to the last element of particular key.

Comment: `id1` is an array. Its index should be mentioned right before calling `id2` Like `$section[0]['id1'][0]['id2'][0]['id3']`. I want like this, but for an example I have mentioned 0 as an index. In that place of 0 I want last element index of that arrays

Comment: I tried your code. Actually it doesn't check for last node. Pls see my updated post. For that example, updation is done in `$parent[1]` instead of last node `$parent[2]`

Comment: yes, I always want the last entry in every array. Am in the process of converting latex document to xml. Am getting data from latex and storing into an array. Data should be appended to the array. So that I need to append data to the last element of every array.

Comment: [Q35484259 - search to end of the first path](http://pastebin.com/CTNMicm6). You will need to download the Sources again as I added routines to return `currentPath` information. [Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/523698)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! It fails, if $parent[2]-> [b-key[1] ->"16"=>array().

Comment: Did you look at the [Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/523698)? Your key information is not the same as that demonstration. The key check is for exact match (===). What you need to be aware of that all numeric keys of an array, even when strings, are **always** converted to **integer** by PHP. So the key used **must** be **16** (integer)  not _"16"_ (string) as the types will not match. I assure you that the code works fine.

Comment: Why does the code use `exact match` (===) rather than  '=='? Easy, PHP `type juggling` messed me up when I first used it! The issue is that when PHP compares different types is 'converts' one of the values to look like the other. Now, when you use a replacement target key  such as `b_key`, PHP looks in the table and sees an integer key. _It then converts the 'b_key' to a integer which gives a result of zero!_ This matches with any zero keys it comes across and updates them!  Your table has zero (0) entry keys! So, the only answer is to use `exact match` for keys ;-/

Answer (score 2):

If I read your comment correctly, you know all the keys and want to add an element to an array that can be reached through those keys.

In that case, all you need to append it to the end of that element, is:

```
$section['id1']['id2']['id3'][] = $the_array_you_want_to_add;
```

**Edit:** If there is a layer more and you need to get the last element of `$section` first, you can use something like:

```
$last_key_of_section = end(array_keys($section));
$section[$last_key_of_section]['id1']['id2']['id3'][] = $the_array_you_want_to_add;
```

Comment: I have updated an example in the post. Actually I need to get last element of `$section`first, then from that element I need to get `id1` .

Comment: Thank you jeroen! it works. But If I want to get `id2` from the last element of `id1`, how can I do it? How to do for `id1` array as `$section`.  Should it be like  `$section[$last_key_of_section]['id1']id1[$last_key_of_id1]['id2']` ?

Comment: if key has an array element. How to access the last element of particular key?

Comment: I think am confusing you :( Actually its not about last key, I want last element of array. That array would be the value of key . If I want to get last element of simple array  I could use `end($array)`. If key has an array. I should access the last element of array which is a value of key. So, I should use like `end("keyname")`, here keyname has an array as a value so it can be passed to `end` method?

Comment: @Learning `end(array_keys($array))` *is* the key of the last element of the array, regardless if you use numeric or string keys. So you can use that at any level.

Comment: `end(array_keys($array))` will ouput the list of keys in the last element of array. For example, keys are key1 ,key2 and key3.  key3 has an array as a value. I will push element to key1,key2  and when I come to key3, its an array. So here I should go the last element of key3 and push the content. `end($array)` => `end("key3")` I want like this. I don't want to retrieve keys. I want to get the last element of keyarray

Comment: I have updated my approach to get the output. Is any alternative way possible?

Comment: @Learning Like I said, `end(array_keys($array))` ***is*** the key of the last element of the array so `count($section)-1` and `end(array_keys($section))` will give you exactly the same result for a 0-indexed sequential array. The difference is that `end(array_keys($section))` will also work if there are indices missing in the array keys and / or when the keys are strings instead of integers.

Answer (score 1):

demonstrating my comment:

```
$ref = &$section;
while (is_array(end($ref))) {
    $key = key($ref);
    $ref = &$ref[$key];
}
array_push($ref, array('1','2','3'));
```

Comment: It works. But I need to insert by using key name. For example, If I want to insert an element or array to `"content3"` how can I specify key name to the end of array element?

Comment: what @jeroean said.   if you know all the keys, this is trivial.  `array_merge($section['id1']['id2']['id3'], array('more','values'));`

Comment: key has an array as a value. How to get last element of key(array)?

Answer (score 1):

This is 'redo' of the code as the previous answer didn't do what anyone wanted.

Requirement:

Given:

- 1) a `root` such as `$section[0]`
- 2) an array of data to add (`$newData`)
- 3) The key of an 'entry', with an empty array, to add the data to.

Result:

- Replace the current empty array  with the `$newData`.

As this is a `tree`, I use the term `$node` to refer to entries in it.

How I choose to approach it.

1) Imagine you have a `class` (TreeWalk) that can 'visit' every node in the tree.

2) It can run any `callable` (visitor) on the node.

3) The node can be modified by the `visitor`

So, given that the `TreeWalk` class exists then the means to do what is required becomes:

- Write a `visitor` to identify the required `node` and update it.

That is what is provided here.

I will provide the 'TreeWalk' class but that is a 'general treewalk' class that is used to run the 'nodeProcessor' that will update the correct node.

#### Sources and Demonstration:

- [TreeWalk Interface at pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/BMZNJjMw)
- [TreeWalk Class at pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/wKuKrPTv)
- [Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/523218)

_Update: Added code to do what the OP asked for...

- [Q35484259 - search to end of the first path](http://pastebin.com/CTNMicm6)
- [Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/523698)

#### The Code (nodeProcessor):

*1) The data it uses:*

```
// new data to add to the node 
$updateData  = array( 'key' => 16, // This must be the correct type i.e string '16' will not match!
                      'data' => array('name666' => 'Kilroy_666', 
                                      'contents666' => 
                                      'Contents_666', 
                                      'id666' => array())
               );
```

*2) The code to be run at every node in the tree*

```
/*
* It can be any `callable`... I use a closure but it could be a function or a method
*
* It will use:
*    o $tree                : instance passed as a parameter
*
*    o $tree->currentKey    : identify which node to update  
*    o $tree->currentNode   : a reference to the node identified by the currentKey 
* 
*    o $tree->processorData : This can be any data that you need for this routine
*                              to do what you want.
*
*          we have: array('key'  => 16,
                          'data' => array('hello', 'node 16'))  
*
*    it needs to identify the correct node and update it with the new data
*/

$updateNode = function (TreeWalk $tree) {

    if ($tree->currentKey === $tree->processorData['key']) {
        $path = $tree->showCurrentPath();
        $tree->currentNode = $tree->processorData['data'];
        $tree->endTreeWalk = true;
        return $path; 
    }
};
```

#### Run the code:

```
$tree = new TreeWalk($parent, $updateNode, $updateData);
$tree->treeWalk();
```

#### TreeWalk Interface:

```
<?php 

/*
 * The class can be found here: http://pastebin.com/wKuKrPTv
 */

Interface ITreeWalk {

    /**
    * This class processes `paths` is a tree made from arrays
    * 
    * You can provide a 'nodeProcessor' which is amy `callable` that will be 
    * run against every node.
    * 
    * Also available is the `current path` through the arrays to get to the `currentNode`.
    * 
    */


    /**
    * A reference to the current node so it can be updated 
    * 
    * @property mixed $currentNode
    */

    /**
    * The key of the currentData - readonly 
    * 
    * @propert mixed $currentKey
    */

    /**
     * The 'current' stack of nodes in this path to reach this `currentNode`
     *
     * This is a 'stack'. The 'path' is all the entries combined.
     *
     *  Each path entry is: array('key' => $currentKey, 'data' => $currentNode) 
     *
     * @property array $currentPath
     */

    /**
     * Available data to the nodeProcesor
     *
     * @property mixed $processorData
     */

    /**
     * The Output
     *
     * @property array $processorResults
     */

    /**
    * Terminate the processing of any further nodes 
    * 
    * @property boolean $endTreeWalk
    */ 


    /**
     * Build the class but do not run it...
     *
     * Provides a default NodeProcessor if you don't provide one.
     *    o The default processor builds string paths that look like  array paths
     *
     * @param array $tree
     * @param callable $processNode        - optional
     * @param processorData                - optional
     */
//    public function __construct(array &$tree,
//                                /* callable */ $processNode = null,
//                               /* mixed    */ $processorData = null);


    /**
     * This routine makes this class rather useful as you can use any callable.
     * 
     * The nodeProcessor accepts one parameter:
     *   o the instance of the 'TreeWalk'
     * 
     * It has some useful items of data available to it: 
     *   1) The `currentNode` - this is a reference so the node can be updated
     *   2) The `currentKey`  - this is the `array index' of the 'currentNode'
     * 
     *   3) The `processorData` - This is anything that you decide you need when processing
     *      the `currentNode`. 
     * 
     *   4) The full path that leads to this node.
     *      This is useful as it can be checked as part of the search conditions
     *      if you wish. 
     *
     * @param callable $nodeProcessor
     */
    public function setNodeProcessor(/* callable */ $nodeProcessor);

    /**
    * This is the data used by the `nodeProcessor` it can be anything.
    * 
    * Normally, an array?
    * 
    * @param mixed $data
    * @return void
    */
    public function setProcessorData($data);

    /**
     * Any walue returned from the 'nodeProcessor' will be stored added to this array.
     *    
     * Return a list of results were generated by the 'nodeProcessor'
     * @return array
     */
     public function results();

    /**
     * Process all the  nodes.
     * 
     * @param mixed optional - The data to be used by the `nodeProcessor`
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function treeWalk($processorData = null);


    /**
    * show the current path as text
    * 
    * What if you don't use `foreach` - is it easier to understand? It is for me...
    * 
    * Path stucture:
    *   1) root node                                       (required) 
    *   2) an iteration of intermediate nodes              (optional) - makes sense
    *   3) end data node                                   (optional) ! 
    *        - what? yes - what if path is just the root ;-/ 
    * 
    * @return string
    */    
    public function showCurrentPath();


    /**
     * If you don't provide a callable to generate paths then this will be used.
     *
     * It generates a list string paths to all the leaf nodes.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    // public function defaultNodeProcessor();
}
```

Comment: I want to  append to the last element of  GIVEN KEY NAME. From my example, I want to append to the last element of `b-key` .So last element of `b-key` is `b-key[3]` In that append data to `16`(keyname). Should not find for empty array alone, because many keys would have empty array values. Should find for last elemnt of givenkeyname. Updated my post pls see it.

Comment: ya, first argument node should be last element. Second argument is not $lastKeyToFind, its $keyToFind